# Pyside main app fit different screen sizes

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside, pyside6

I wanted to know how can I set the app size to fit the screen size.
Basically I have been testing my app on a big monitor(app size 1838x980) and now I am testing it on a smaller monitor and so now the app overlaps the entire screen.

In addition, if i drag my app across different screen sizes, the app changes size.

Is there a way to have a dynamic app size to always match the size of the monitor?

Or maybe a solution would be to show fullscreen?

I was wondering if anyone had an answer to this, but if you would like demo code I could write something simple.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried [showMaximized](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showMaximized)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably read out the screensize with `QScreen.geometry`. This should hold the geometry of the screen you are using. See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qscreen.html#geometry-prop).

If you want it dynamic the best way should be an event which detects the end of the movement of the window. Since the movement is, like @musicamante correctly mentioned, controlled by the OS/WindowManager, this needs to be achieved differently a differs from system to system.

Comment: QDragMoveEvent has absolutely **NOTHING** to do with dragging windows across screens. It also is **not** a slot, but an event class.

Comment: About the the slot/event confusion you are right. But as I understood OP correctly his problem are different resolutions while dragging the window across the screens. So analysing the geometry while dragging is a possible solution. I am open to better solutions. Another event?

Comment: "Dragging" a window is **not** related to drag and drop, it's just about moving it. It may be handled by the OS or *eventually* by implementing `mouseMoveEvent()`, but certainly not by drag and drop event handlers. Besides, a drop event is *received* by a widget when something gets dropped *on* it, which clearly wouldn't be the case.

Comment: Now I understand and yes you are absolutly right about the event this is not the right one.